# Hudson triggering ant bulid

Tags: git, ant, hudson

I want to achieve like this ,"when i check-in my code in git repository hudson assosiated with git should trigger ant  or maven build scripts " Can any one help me on this...???

Answer (score 4):

So, how far are you in this endeavor?

- Have you installed Hudson?
- Have you managed to get Hudson running?
- Have you been able to open Hudson up in a web browser?
- Have you been able to configure Hudson?
- Do you have a job defined in Hudson for your project?
- Do you have the GIT plugin installed. It should be there by default in all versions after 2.10.
- Have you gotten Hudson talking to your GIT repository? Does the machine Hudson is running on have access to your repository?
- Have you any experience with Hudson or Jenkins before?

Considering Hudson's main task is to checkout and build a project whenever a new version of that project is in the repository, it shouldn't be too difficult.